# extract part of a file path between pattern using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to extract data from a list of file paths as I am looking to create a log of files that have completed loading. The problem is that each file path is inconsistent so I need to look for part of the file path between two regex patterns.

For example say I want to pull out two pieces of information...let's say, the data between /system/.../ and another piece of data between /data/.../sales/

```
/user/project-x/system/ibm/nyc/data/customers/sales/yyyymmdd
/user/project-x/system/mysql/data/regional/sales/yyyymmdd
/user/project-x/system/mysql/london/data/customers/sales/yyyymmdd
/user/project-x/system/oracle/data/tokyo-customers/Sales/yyyymmdd
```

So when I run the awk script I would be left with...

```
ibm      customers
mysql    regional
mysql    customers
oracle   tokyo-customers
```

Is there anyway to do that type of file path splitting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that your path parts are fixed, so no need to use regexes.
Field separation does the trick:

```
awk -F/ '{print $4,$7}' test.txt
```

(where `test.txt` is your input file)

Basically you're telling `awk` to consider slashes as field separator, and print field #4 and #7.

But to answer your question with field lookup do this (more complicated though)

```
awk -F/ '{a="???";b="???";for (i=0;i<NF;i++) {if (tolower($i)=="system") a= $(i+1); if (($i=="data") && (tolower($(i+2))=="sales")) b = $(i+1)}; print a,b}' test.txt
```

This will split the fields as before, but will lookup previous/next field values and print next/previous field. Even if the fields are not at fixed positions that will work.
If pattern is nowhere to be found, this will display `???` instead.

I have included lowercase conversion since there's an occurrence of `Sales` as mixed case.

Comment: Thanks for fast response and almost perfect, the problem is I can't rely on the filed number as even in my simple example the columns I want are not all in column $7. Is there a way to do something like count the position of the last column and do something like $n-2?

Comment: see my edit. I realized that I was not really answering the question that was asked.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed -E 's_.*/system/([^/]+).*/data/([^/]+)/[Ss]ales/.*_\1 \2_'
```

- `.*/system/([^/]+).*` matches the portion after `/system/`, and upto next `/`, and put in captured group 1
- `/data/([^/]+)/[Ss]ales/` matches the portion between `/data/` and `/sales/` (or `/Sales/`) and put in second captured group
- In the replacement the the captured groups are used, separated by space

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
/user/project-x/system/ibm/nyc/data/customers/sales/yyyymmdd
/user/project-x/system/mysql/data/regional/sales/yyyymmdd
/user/project-x/system/mysql/london/data/customers/sales/yyyymmdd
/user/project-x/system/oracle/data/tokyo-customers/Sales/yyyymmdd

$ sed -E 's_.*/system/([^/]+).*/data/([^/]+)/[Ss]ales/.*_\1 \2_' file.txt
ibm customers
mysql regional
mysql customers
oracle tokyo-customers
```

Comment: That is great, very flexible too!